# Contain pattern matching in expectedExceptionMessageRegExp TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I have a script in TestNg to handle expected exception

```
@Test(expectedExceptions= {IOException.class}, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp ="[a-z]{4}\s[a-z]{7}\s[a-z]{4}")
public void testSixContainWith() throws Exception{
    throw new IOException("Pass Message Test");     
}
```

While compiling in eclipse IDE, the given pattern is showing compilation error.

I tried other possible pattern also, but all with same compilation error

1. `\w{4}\s\w{7}\s\w{4}`
2. `Pass\s\w{7}\sTest`

Comment: Backslashes should be doubled; regexes in Java are in string literals, and in string literals a backslash is written "\\"

Comment: I tried the same with `"[a-z]{4}\\s[a-z]{7}\\s[a-z]{4}"`, but the compilation is- The exception was thrown with the wrong message: expected "[a-z]{4}\s[a-z]{7}\s[a-z]{4}" but got "Pass Message Test"

Comment: Well, at least it doesn't show a compile error anymore, does it? And it is normal that the test fails; `P` does not match `[a-z]`. Problem solved!

Comment: `[a-z]` does not match upper case `P`.

Comment: Thanks all, for pointing out the given mistake.

Answer (score 0):

"\" It is a special char
Then you must Escape this char.

Try:

> "[a-z]{4}\\s[a-z]{7}\\s[a-z]{4}"